# How to cat a fixed unknown number of file?

Tags: bash

I am working on a mini project where I have zipped logs displayed in this way :

```
youyou.log
youyou.log.1.gz
youyou.log.2.gz
youyou.log.3.gz
```

Where I have to unzip them, then merge them from the highest index to `youyou.log`

The thing is, sometime I could have only one file sometimes more but unknown it could go till `youyou.log.n.gz`

I started to write something who does work but it's not elegant at all.
I have assumed a fixed number of .gz files and gives some error that I have ignored later on.

```
main.sh    
#!/bin/bash

gunzip *.gz 
cat youyou.log.7 youyou.log.6 youyou.log.5 youyou.log.4 youyou.log.3 .log.2 youyou.log.1 youyou.log > youyou_complete.log
```

then ignored like this:

```
 main.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Is there a better way to deal with this, please? Thank you

Comment: Would it be okay if I provided a script in Python to do it?

Comment: `cat *.log.* *.log > youyou_complete.log` maybe? You could also use `find` and `xargs`.

Comment: @MegaEmailman I have zero knowledge in Python, unfortunately, but I would be curious to see it in Python please ?

Comment: I'll go ahead and try it.  If you have Python installed, you could just run the script.

Comment: Hi @FelixKling, I tried but it will scramble all my timestamps... I need them on a specific order to keep track of the timing.

Comment: @Mohamed : Where do you have timestamps in your example???

Comment: @user1934428,  when I open the file, I have date and time.

Comment: @Mohamed : So you don't mean that you sort by index number, but by modification time? In this case, you should update your posting, because it is not clear from the text.

Comment: What's the file order supposed to be if you have `youyou.log.8.gz`,  `youyou.log.9.gz`, `youyou.log.10.gz`, `youyou.log.11.gz` too?  Do you need to sort the names by version number, or is straight alphanumeric sorting OK?  The difference is that with numeric sorting, files 9 and 10 will be adjacent, but with alphanumeric sorting, 10 will be adjacent to 1.  It's not hard to guess that you want numeric and not alphanumeric sorting, but it is an important difference that you should cover in your specification.  And if you ever wondered why numbers like `youyou.log.0001.gz` are used, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
find . -name "youyou.log.*.gz" -maxdepth 1 | sort -rn -t. -k4 | xargs zcat | cat - youyou.log > youyou_complete.log
```

It assumes you do not uncompress the `*.gz` files in advance.

**[Explanations]**

- `find . -name "youyou.log.*.gz" -maxdepth 1` finds files with the specified
  pattern in the current directory, then creates a list such as:

  ```
  ./youyou.log.1.gz
  ./youyou.log.2.gz
  ./youyou.log.3.gz
  [snip]
  ./youyou.log.9.gz
  ./youyou.log.10.gz
  ```
- `sort -rn -t. -k4` first separates the passed filenames on ".",
  then the internal list will be something like:

  ```
  (null)  /youyou  log  1  gz
  (null)  /youyou  log  2  gz
  (null)  /youyou  log  3  gz
  [snip]
  (null)  /youyou  log  9  gz
  (null)  /youyou  log  10 gz
  ```
- The `-k4` option tells `sort` to sort the list of filenames by the 4th
  column (1, 2, 3, ..). The `-n` option specifies the numerical sort
  and the `-r` option reverses the result of comparison.
- Now the folowing list is sent to the standard input of `xargs` command:

  ```
  ./youyou.log.10.gz
  ./youyou.log.9.gz
  [snip]
  ./youyou.log.3.gz
  ./youyou.log.2.gz
  ./youyou.log.1.gz
  ```
- `xargs` creates a command which is composed of the argument(s) followed
  by the arguments read from the standard input.
  Then the command will look like:

  ```
  zcat ./youyou.log.10.gz ./youyou.log.9.gz ... ./youyou.log.1.gz
  ```
- `zcat` uncompresses the list of files and writes the uncompressed data
  on standard output by merging the data in the argument order.
- The final command `cat - youyou.log` concatenates the standard input and
  `youyou.log` in the specified order then redirects the result to
  `youyou_complete.log`.

If your `sort` supports `-z` option, it will be better to say:

```
find . -name "youyou.log.*.gz" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -z -rn -t. -k4 | xargs -0 zcat | cat - youyou.log > youyou_complete.log
```

- `-print0` option tells `find` to use a null character `\0` as a delimiter
  of the list of filenames instead of newlines. `-z` option to `sort` and
  `-0` option to `xargs` cooperate with it.
  If the filenames contain whitespaces or newlines,
  `xargs` incorrectly splits the argument list on them. This may not
  happen in the given examples as the filenames obviously do not
  contain whitespaces but such a consideration may be useful
  to make the script safer and future-proof (IMHO).

Comment: it's working perfectly both are great, can you explain the meaning of both lines please ?

Comment: @tshiono : Why are you going via NUL-termination instead of \n here? This would be an issue if we had file names with embedded spaces, but with the file pattern we have here, this can't happen, I think. Also, since all files are in the same directory, maybe a `-maxdepth 1` on the `find` would be appropriate, lest it might pick up some file matching the pattern in a subdirectory.

Comment: @Mohamed I've updated my answer with some explanations. Hope it will help.

Comment: @user1934428 thanks for your comment. I make a habit to use a null delimiter
in `find` if possible even if it is not necessary at the moment.
I suppose it may be safer and reduce future maintenance cost.
This is my personal opinion and I won't force others to do it ;).
As of the `-maxdepth 1` option I 100% agree with you. it will be
more likely to happen than the filenames with whitespaces. I've updated
my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Python

```py
import os
path = "/home/user/logs/"
listOfFiles = os.listdir(path)
mainFile = open("youyou.log.complete", "a")
for file in listOfFiles:
    os.system("gunzip ", file)
listOfUnzipped = os.listdir(path)
for file in listOfUnzipped:
    secondaryFile = open(file, "r")
    text = secondaryFile.read()
    mainFile.write(text)
    mainFile.write("\r\n")
    secondaryFile.close()
mainFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
touch tmp.log
gzip -c tmp.log > tmp.log.gz

for i in $(dir -r *.gz); do
  cat $i >> tmp.log.gz
done

gunzip tmp.gz

cat youyou.log >> tmp.log
```

i have not test it yet, while the code could be self explained.

the only thing i am worrying about is that the `.gz` file order of `dir` output, if you have log file with name `youyou.log.11, youyou.log.22` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is to get the files in the descending order, and your specification is a bit unclear, what you mean by this. For instance, if you have youyou.log.32 and youyou.log.4 - which one should come first? If you are interested in strict character order, you can use `ls` to get an appropriately sorted list (with all the pitfalls of `ls`), i.e.

```
# bash
cat $(ls -r youyou.log.[0-9]*) >youyou.complete.log
```

or you can switch from bash to zsh, where filename generation can be done with sorting.
Example:

```
# zsh
cat youyou.log.[0-9]*(On) >youyou.complete.log
```

The `(On)`sorts descending on the name. This would sort youyou.log.32 after youyou.log.4. If you can arrange that the log files have an approprite timestamp, using `(Om)` instead of `(On)` would sort descending on modification time.

If you don't have a timestamp, but want to sort the files "numerically", i.e. youyou.log.32 earlier than youyou.log.4, because 4 is smaller than 32, the best solution I can think of would be to use `sort`:

```
# bash
cat $(echo youyou.log.[0-9]*|fmt -w 1|sort -n -r -t. -k 3) >youyou.complete.log
```

The `fmt` ensures that we have one *youyou* file per line, and the `sort` sorts numerically (-n) on the 3rd field (-k 3), where the field delimiter is a period (-t.).

Comment: you can't have .32 and .4 when logs are generated, the oldest one has the highest index. Depending on the uptime of this system, either it generates one log sometimes 2 files ( youyou.log and youyou.log.1), and so on. I will give a try on those commands

Comment: @Mohamed : Why not? Which log is generated after youyou.log.9? Wouldn't it be youyou.log.10?

Comment: The system was no limit as long as it's powered on, also it will depends all issues occurring in this system. Yes .log.10 would be the next if it's generated

Comment: In this case, you can also have a log.32, and you need to decide whether it should be considered later as log.4 (because 32 is larger than 4, seen as a number) or earlier (because 32 is smaller than 4, when seen as a string). Hence, you need to decide, as I explained in my post, whether you sort numerically or by name. For instance, the solution proposed by toshiono (which is better than mine anyway) uses numeric sorting. Or, if you *do* have a reliable modification time stamp available, you can simply sort by this.